# limitations of using @Html.EditorForModel

Tags: css, asp.net, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. I have the following model class :-

```
public class Details4
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public string RESOURCENAME { set; get; }
        [Display (Name="Account Name")]
        [Required]
        public string ACCOUNTNAME { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Resource type")]
        [Required]
        public string RESOURCETYPE { set; get; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required]
        public string PASSWORD { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { set; get; }
        [Display(Name= "URL")]
        [Url]
        public string RESOURCEURL { set; get; }
        [Display(Name="Owner Name")]
        [Required]
        public string OWNERNAME { set; get; }
        [Display(Name = "Resource Group Nam")]
        public string RESOURCEGROUPNAME { set; get; }
        [JsonProperty("Domain")]
        public string DomainName { set; get; }
        [JsonProperty("DNSNAME")]
        public string DNSNAME { set; get; }
         [Display(Name = "Department")]
        public string DEPARTMENT { set; get; }
         [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public string LOCATION { set; get; }
        public List<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD> RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD { set; get; }
    }

 public class RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD
    {
        public string CUSTOMLABEL { set; get; }
        public string CUSTOMVALUE { set; get; }
    }
```

now i usually use `@Html.EditorFor()` & `LabelFor()` at the field level. but for this model i wanted to start using `@Html.EditorForModel` as i will have less markup on the view:-

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

now the result of this was not 100% what i was expecting:-

[image]

so can any one advice how i can overcome these limitations:-

1. Is there a way to have the ResourceType field as a drodownlist ? . now if i am rendering separate fields i can use `@Html.DropDownlistFor` .. but not sure how i can handle this when using `@Html.EditorForModel` ?
2. is there a way to modify the generated layout ?,, now usual all over my application i have the following layout for the label --> text box:-

   ```
   <div>
       <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME)</span> 
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME) 
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME)                                              
   </div>
   ```

where i have the label & text at the same line, and i wrap the label with a class=f which will show the label in bold font. so can i modify the generated output from the `EditorForModel` to have the label and the text box at the same line, instead of being on 2 separate lines?

3. will i be able to force the EditorForModel to render the `RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD` list columns ?

Comment: `EditorForModel()` will use the default EditorTemplates for each type in your model. If you want specific templates then you need to create you own `EditorTemplates`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but how i can have a dropdownlist for my resourceType field if i use EditorForModel() ? and is there a way to force the EditorForModel to render a complex entity such as the RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD in my case?

Comment: You can decorate the property with `[UIHint]` and create a template for the property and (cringe) use a `ViewBag` property for the `SelectList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i got your point ,, seems a lot of work .. i thought that using EditorForModel will let me to write  less code espically on the view ,, but it will add extra effort on writing custom templates ..  from your own experience due you usually use EditorforModel ? or you use EditorFor at each property level instead ? or both of them ?

Comment: Personally I never use `EditorForModel()` and the only time I use `EditorFor()` is when I have a `EditorTemplate` for a complex type (either a single object or a collection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so even when you want to render an input field you do not use EditorFor(model=>model.Name) ?? you write html direclty without using html helpers ?

Comment: God no. I use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or `CheckBoxFor()` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke but what will @Html.TextBoxFor() offers that EditorFor does not ? using Editorfor will renders HTML markup based on the datatype of the property, while using TextBoxfor will not be smart enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111166/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-g).

Answer (score 6):

`EditorForModel` default template is not highly customizable. You should write an *EditorTemplate* to solve all your problems. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx).
You will have to write all the properties manually but you will do it only once for each model. Put the template in the folder `EditorTemplates/` and your whole app can use it. To answer your bullets:

1. Now you write your own template, you can use any type of input for your properties. The default editor for `string` type is a *textbox* (*dropdown* for `enum` type).
2. You will have to write your own layout in the template. That is exactly what you want.
3. You can also write an editor template for `RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD` and use it in your template. You can write a template even for `IEnumerable<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD>` :

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD>
   @foreach(var customModel in Model)
   {
       @Html.LabelFor(m => customModel.CUSTOMLABEL )
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => customModel.CUSTOMVALUE )
   }
   ```

And use it like (in your main template):

```
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD )
```

There is also something called *DisplayTemplate* if you want to change how the `DisplayFor` works for the model.

Answer (score 2):

1.You can use [UIHint("custom_template")] above your model field.
For example:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [UIHint("gender_template")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you should create gender_template.cshtml in Shared/EditorTemplates like the picture below.

[image]

example code in file gender_template.cshtml.

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "",
    new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "Male", Text = "Male" },
            new { Value = "Female", Text = "Female" },
        },
        "Value",
        "Text",
        Model
    )
)
```

Then in the View page code is

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Class1 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

The result after run view page is

[image]

You can make more custom template as you need.

2. You can do like @html.EditorFor, To use @Html.DisplayFor syntax you should create template file in Shared/DisplayTemplates, You can write/add your own html syntax in the template file.